# Events inside events at jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a very basic question but I couldn't find an answer. (I might be looking for the wrong terms...)

Sometimes I feel that I need to add an event inside another event in order to share variables, for example. But I've realized the events inside can be fired multiple times depending on the times the parent event has been fired.

Here's a basic example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/

```
$('.demo').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').show(function(){
        $('#link').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked"); //fired multiple times
            $(this).parent().hide(); 
        });
    });
});
```

If you click more than once in the "First Click" you will see how the second event is fired multiple times.

I am not looking for that behavior. I know [I can avoid it using delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/4/) making use of `.on()` but... isn't there any other way to avoid the events inside to be fired multiple times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to use jQuery's [**`one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

> `one()` -  Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is
>   executed at most once per element.

In this case, it would be:

```
$('#link').one('click', function(){
   alert("Clicked"); //fired multiple times
   $(this).parent().hide(); 
});
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.one()`, which binds the event just once per element:

```
$('.demo').click(function () {
    $('.hidden').show(function () {
        $('#link').one('click', function () {
            alert("Clicked");
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/3/) and [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: (+1) Works well. But Zenith answered about 2 mins before. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Alvaro, yeah, I saw the "1 New Answer" message come up as I was finishing up my answer.  I suppose if I had posted "Use `.one()`" right away and *then* edited with the fiddle link...but I suppose Zenith could say the same thing!  ;)  Thanks for the upvote, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a variable as a flag: [**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/5/)

```
var clicked = false;
$('.demo').click(function(){
    clicked = true;
    $('.hidden').show(function(){
        $('#link').click(function(){
            if(clicked == true){
                alert("Clicked");
                $(this).parent().hide();
                clicked = false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its an alternative but maybe not the most clean and simple :) Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can either fire it once like all others said or you can unbind the click event every time (Just a different aproach)

```
$('.demo').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').show(function(){
        $('#link').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked");
            $(this).parent().hide();
            $('#link').unbind('click');
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle :).](http://jsfiddle.net/mRc9K/8/)